# How do I assign a std::pair that have one of it's component typed const?

Tags: c++, std-pair

I'm trying to code an associative container compatible with std::map. To do so, I have to create an insert method that accept a new item in the form of an std::pair with the first component of a const type. For example : `std::pair<const int, int> p`.

The problem I have is that such an object can't be assigned to another. So in the inner code of my MapCompatibleContainer, I can't copy the new pair to the private variable (a std::vector).

How can I work around this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you say, you cannot assign to a const object.

The standard containers solve this by allocating raw memory and construct the object in place. Copy construction still works.

Also, the associative containers store each element in a separate memory block, so that they don't have to be copied later.

Answer (score 0):

There is a helper function in the `<utility>` section of the standard library which holds a `std::make_pair` function.  If you use that you can take your pair and do the following:

```
foo.insert( std::make_pair( bar.first, bar.second ) );
```

where I'm assuming the "foo" is your own implementation of an object that is compatible to "map."

Comment: This still doesn't work if I need to do something like: foo = std::make_pair(bar.first, bar.second) because the = operator is still invoked after the creation of the std::pair.

Comment: @Mathieu Page you do realize that underneath the hood, the part not exposed to a client of your container, you can store the objects as non-const and only return const objects.